# Applying google currency converter to all prices on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency

what I am trying to do is convert all prices on a page with jquery, ajax and google currency.

I found this, it's working fine.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
     //Get the values
     var amount = $('#amount').val();
     var from  = $('#from').val();
     var to = $('#to').val();
     var params = "amount=" + amount + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to ;

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "currency-converter.php",
       data: params ,
       success: function(data){
            $('#converted_value').html(amount + from +" is equal to : " +data);

       }
     });
    }) ;
```

How can i apply this to a div class on a page? Lets say i have a priceEuro class;

```
<div class="product">
      <div class="priceEuro"><?php the_field('price1'); ?></div>
</div>

<div class="product">
      <div class="priceEuro"><?php the_field('price2'); ?></div>
</div>

<div class="product">
      <div class="priceEuro"><?php the_field('price3'); ?></div>
</div>
```

Now i want to convert all different prices and add results to products like this,

```
$('.priceEuro').each(function () {

                         var amount = $(this).val();
             var params = "amount=" + amount + "&from=EUR" + "&to=USD" ;

             $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "currency-converter.php",
               data: params ,
               success: function(data){
                $(this).append("<div class="priceUsd">'+ data +'</div>");

               }
             });
```

I know it's not right these way so what's the solution? Thanks.

---

Thanks to @UnTechie now i am getting results,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.each($('.priceEuro'), function () {

     var amount = $(this).text();
     var dataString = "amount=" + amount + "&from=EUR" + "&to=USD";

         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "chalo/themes/chalo/ajax_converter.php",
           data: dataString,
           success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $(this).append('<div class="priceUsd">'+ data +'</div>');
           }
         });
    });

});
```

but i couldn't append these results after each div, is this wrong?

```
$(this).append('<div class="priceUsd">'+ data +'</div>');
```

---

ok, i found the problem. `this` is not automatically a reference to the right object in the ajax callback.

now it's working like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.each($('.priceEuro'), function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     var amount = $(this).text();
     var dataString = "amount=" + amount + "&from=EUR" + "&to=USD";

         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "chalo/themes/chalo/ajax_converter.php",
           data: dataString,
           success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $this.append('<div class="priceUsd">'+ data +'</div>');
           }
         });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jquery.each(http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

This is how your code should look ..

```
$.each($('.priceEuro'), function () {
 //Your code goes here ... Use $(this) to access each element

});
```

Comment: thanks but i couldn't add these results after each div now, any help?